# container scrolling lwuit in devices that dont support touch

Tags: scroll, lwuit, lwuit-container

I develop with lwuit to Nokia and Blackberry.

I have a problem with `Container` scrolling in the devices that dont support touch.I have a `Container` that consist some components (this components are cell rendered but not at list). The scroll in touch mode work fine but in the other device the scroll is very slow.

do anyone recognize this problem?

it is solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have a focusable component at the end of form, if that's the case what you can do is add a dummy kind of label field on lwuit form at last and just set the .focusable property of that label to true. I guess that should work.

Answer (score 0):

set the focusable property of container to **true**.

```
containerObj.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: I try it before i asked hehre and  its didn't work. i try addtional the function form.setCyclicFocus(false) but the container slide is very fast